# Abstracting into a common method

Tags: groovy

New to Groovy, and trying to get my head around extracting common code into neat methods.

How would I write a Groovy method that could be called to make an assertion and could be used in these two very similar examples:

```
boolean foundName = groups.any({ it.@'name' == expectedResult.name.toString()})
Assert.assertTrue(foundName, "name: ${expectedResult.name.toString()}")

... ... 

boolean foundDisc = groups.any({ it.@'disc' == expectedResult.disc.toString()})
Assert.assertTrue(foundDisc, "disc: ${expectedResult.disc.toString()}")
```

I broke that into two lines to show my intent. Passing the expected value is simple enough, but how do I pass the other?. Something that has a signature along these lines:

```
void assertAnyAttributeEquals(??? it ???, String attributeName, String expectedResult)
```

Comment: Your example asserts `foundNumber`, but I assume that should be `foundDisc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful technique here is to use string interpolation as the attribute/field specifier. For example:

```
def myAssert = { groups, attr, expectedResult ->
    def found = groups.any({ it.@"${attr}" == expectedResult."${attr}".toString() })
    assert found
}
```

Here is a complete, working example:

```
class Result {
    def name
    def disc
}

def xmlStr = '''
<doc>
    <groups name="hello" />
    <groups disc="abc" />
</doc> 
'''

def myAssert = { groups, attr, expectedResult ->
    def found = groups.any({ it.@"${attr}" == expectedResult."${attr}".toString() })
    assert found
}

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlStr)

myAssert(xml.groups, 'name', new Result('name': 'hello'))
myAssert(xml.groups, 'disc', new Result('disc': 'abc'))
```